# I'm trying to install django=1.9 on ubuntu using python and I'm getting the following errors for admin login

Tags: python, django, ubuntu

django error displayed on terminal:

```
Not Found: /favicon.ico [21/Apr/2017 07:33:24] 
"GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 1963
Not Found: /favicon.ico [21/Apr/2017 07:33:25] 
"GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 1963 [21/Apr/2017 07:34:23] 
"GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
Internal Server Error: /admin/login/
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/priya/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template 
/utils.py", line 65, in __getitem__
return self._engines[alias]
KeyError: 'django'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/priya/.local/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 126, in 
get_package_libraries
```

And this is the error message displayed on Browser:

InvalidTemplateLibrary at /admin/login/

```
Invalid template library specified. ImportError raised when trying to load 
'django.templatetags.future': cannot import name 'RemovedInDjango110Warning'

  Request Method:   GET
  Request URL:  http://localhost:8000/admin/login/?next=/admin/
  Django Version:   1.11
```

I have installed django=1.9 version and it's showing 1.11

```
  Exception Type:   InvalidTemplateLibrary
  Exception Value:  

  Invalid template library specified. ImportError raised when trying to load 
  'django.templatetags.future': cannot import name 
  'RemovedInDjango110Warning'

   Exception Location:  /home/priya/.local/lib/python3.5/site-
   packages/django/template/backends/django.py in get_package_libraries, 
    line 130
   Python Executable:   /usr/bin/python3
   Python Version:  3.5.2
   Python Path:     

 ['/home/priya/Desktop/project/project',
 '/usr/lib/python35.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-i386-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload',
'/home/priya/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages',
'/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

Comment: Do you have different versions of django installed on python 2 and python3. Try using `python2 manage.py runserver`

Answer (score 0):

`url` is removed from `future` template lib in django 1.9, so if you try to import in your templates like: `{% load url from future %}` it will give import error. If `url` is needed in your template, just use it and delete the import.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/releases/1.9/#features-removed-in-1-9